# Upgrade SQL Server 2012 LocalDB to SQL Server 2014 LocalDB

Tags: visual-studio-2013, localdb

I have a WPF/C# project using VS2013. I created a `.mdf` file and by default it created it as SQL Server 2012 LocalDB. The database now has some rows in it. Is there a way to upgrade this `.mdf` file to SQL Server 2014 LocalDB?